# Compare two arrays of objects, and remove if object value is equal

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, javascript-objects

I've tried modifying some of the similar solutions on here but I keep getting stuck, I believe I have part of this figured out however, the main caveat is that:

Some of the objects have extra keys, which renders my object comparison logic useless.

I am trying to compare two arrays of objects. One array is the original array, and the other array contains the items I want deleted from the original array. However there's one extra issue in that the second array contains extra keys, so my comparison logic doesn't work.

**An example would make this easier, let's say I have the following two arrays:**

```
const originalArray = [{id: 1, name: "darnell"}, {id: 2, name: "funboi"}, 
{id: 3, name: "jackson5"}, {id: 4, name: "zelensky"}];

const itemsToBeRemoved = [{id: 2, name: "funboi", extraProperty: "something"}, 
{id: 4, name: "zelensky", extraProperty: "somethingelse"}];
```

**after running the logic, my final output should be this array:**

`[{id: 1, name: "darnell"}, {id: 3, name: "jackson5"}]`

And here's the current code / logic that I have, which compares but doesn't handle the extra keys. How should I handle this? Thank you in advance.

```
const prepareArray = (arr) => {
  return arr.map((el) => {
    if (typeof el === "object" && el !== null) {
      return JSON.stringify(el);
    } else {
      return el;
    }
  });
};

const convertJSON = (arr) => {
  return arr.map((el) => {
    return JSON.parse(el);
  });
};

const compareArrays = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const currentArray = [...prepareArray(arr1)];
  const deletedItems = [...prepareArray(arr2)];
  const compared = currentArray.filter((el) => deletedItems.indexOf(el) === -1);
  return convertJSON(compared);
};
```

Comment: What _should_ the comparison logic be then?

Comment: Potentially compare just the IDs of the two arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `filter` and `some`? You can extend the filter condition on select properties using `&&`.

```js
const originalArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'darnell' },
  { id: 2, name: 'funboi' },
  { id: 3, name: 'jackson5' },
  { id: 4, name: 'zelensky' },
];
const itemsToBeRemoved = [
  { id: 2, name: 'funboi', extraProperty: 'something' },
  { id: 4, name: 'zelensky', extraProperty: 'somethingelse' },
];
console.log(
  originalArray.filter(item => !itemsToBeRemoved.some(itemToBeRemoved => itemToBeRemoved.id === item.id))
)
```

Or you can generalise it as well.

```js
const originalArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'darnell' },
  { id: 2, name: 'funboi' },
  { id: 3, name: 'jackson5' },
  { id: 4, name: 'zelensky' },
];
const itemsToBeRemoved = [
  { id: 2, name: 'funboi', extraProperty: 'something' },
  { id: 4, name: 'zelensky', extraProperty: 'somethingelse' },
];
function filterIfSubset(originalArray, itemsToBeRemoved) {
  const filteredArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
    let isSubset = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < itemsToBeRemoved.length; j++) {
      // check if whole object is a subset of the object in itemsToBeRemoved
      if (Object.keys(originalArray[i]).every(key => originalArray[i][key] === itemsToBeRemoved[j][key])) {
        isSubset = true;
      }
    }
    if (!isSubset) {
      filteredArray.push(originalArray[i]);
    }
  }
  return filteredArray;
}
console.log(filterIfSubset(originalArray, itemsToBeRemoved));
```

Another simpler variation of the second approach:

```js
const originalArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'darnell' },
  { id: 2, name: 'funboi' },
  { id: 3, name: 'jackson5' },
  { id: 4, name: 'zelensky' },
];
const itemsToBeRemoved = [
  { id: 2, name: 'funboi', extraProperty: 'something' },
  { id: 4, name: 'zelensky', extraProperty: 'somethingelse' },
];
const removeSubsetObjectsIfExists = (originalArray, itemsToBeRemoved) => {
  return originalArray.filter(item => {
    const isSubset = itemsToBeRemoved.some(itemToBeRemoved => {
      return Object.keys(item).every(key => {
        return item[key] === itemToBeRemoved[key];
      });
    });
    return !isSubset;
  });
}
console.log(removeSubsetObjectsIfExists(originalArray, itemsToBeRemoved));
```

Comment: Wow yeah this worked great. I thought I had tried this approach but I had my ! operator placed as itemToBeRemoved.id !== item.id. Huge brain fart. Thanks so much for your help sir you have genuinely made my night

Comment: Didn't even think about the fact that I could add ! in front of itemsToBeRemoved. I just recently started learning javascript, should definitely spend more time practicing this type of logic :)

Comment: In the first one you've to define each individual key, which you want to check. For e.g. I used Id comparison only and which can be extended on name too. Something like !itemsToBeRemoved.some(itemToBeRemoved => itemToBeRemoved.id === item.id && itemToBeRemoved.name === item.name)). Second one doesn't care how many keys are there. Let's say there are 100 items in your object. The code will become messy using first approach.

Answer (score 1):

The example below is a reusable function, the third parameter is the key to which you compare values from both arrays.

***Details are commented in example***

```js
const arr=[{id:1,name:"darnell"},{id:2,name:"funboi"},{id:3,name:"jackson5"},{id:4,name:"zelensky"}],del=[{id:2,name:"funboi",extraProperty:"something"},{id:4,name:"zelensky",extraProperty:"somethingelse"}];

/** Compare arrayA vs. delArray by a given key's value.
--- ex. key = 'id'
**/
function deleteByKey(arrayA, delArray, key) {
  /* Get an array of only the values of the given key from delArray
  --- ex. delList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  */
  const delList = delArray.map(obj => obj[key]);
  
  /* On every object of arrayA compare delList values vs 
 current object's key's value
  --- ex. current obj[id] = 2
  --- [1, 2, 3, 4].includes(obj[id])
  Any match returns an empty array and non-matches are returned 
  in it's own array.
  --- ex. ? [] : [obj]
  The final return is a flattened array of the non-matching objects
  */
  return arrayA.flatMap(obj => delList.includes(obj[key]) ? [] : [obj]);  
};

console.log(deleteByKey(arr, del, 'id'));
```

Comment: Thank you for this and for the detailed comments! It's helped me learn quite a lot on how each step works.

Answer (score 0):

> > let ff = [{ id: 1, name: 'darnell' }, { id: 2, name: 'funboi' },
> > { id: 3, name: 'jackson5' },
> > { id: 4, name: 'zelensky' }]

```
let cc = [{ id: 2, name: 'funboi', extraProperty: 'something' },
 { id: 4, name: 'zelensky', extraProperty: 'somethingelse' }]
 let ar = []
 let out = []

const result =  ff.filter(function(i){
ar.push(i.id)
cc.forEach(function(k){
  out.push(k.id)
})
if(!out.includes(i.id)){
  // console.log(i.id, i)
  return i
 }
})
console.log(result)
```